# Implementing loops on the basis of condition in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a set of statements that need to be executed in two different loops; the loops identified on the result of a check condition. There are multiple such sets of this type.

```
Set A : statement 1
        statement 2
        statement 3

Set B : statement 4
        statement 5
        statement 6

and so on..
```

Now they need to be executed as follows:

```
if(condition 1)
    loop over some Loop A
        execute Set A
else if(condition 2)
    loop over some loop B
        execute Set A

These loops can be completely different from each other.
```

Now, for the sake of code clarity, I don't wish to write the code as mentioned above. Another reason being I'll have to make multiple sets in order to group them together.

Is there any mechanism by which I could achieve the following:

```
CHECK_CONDITION_AND_LOOP_HERE
    execute Set A
```

I've tried using macros to achieve this, using **braced-group within expression** but could not . I also tried using **ternary operators** as well as **fall through a switch case** to achieve this, but could not get the same result.

Is there any way in C using which I could achieve the desired behavior?

Sample code for the problem:

```
if(condition A)
    for(i=0; i<10; i++, k*=2) {
        execute Set A;  //Operations performed here use variable k
    }
else if(condition B)
    for(j=5; j<75; j+=5, k*=arr[j]) {
        execute Set A;  //Operations performed here use variable k
    }
```

Comment: Determine the start and end values conditionally, then loop? Or make "execute set A" a function? Or even make looping and "execute set A" a function? There are many ways that are better than macros.

Comment: Its not just the start end values based loop. Updating the question for better clarity.

Comment: These half-baked pseudocode examples don't make your requirements clear, I'm afraid. If you don't want to duplicate common code, make it a separate function, whether it is `exec(A)` or `exec_A()`. You don't say how the loops differ, but you could also write some iterator-like function and determine that conditionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer to Version 1 of the question:**

Given that the only difference is the range of values over which the statements are executed, you can use a couple of variables to store the range end-points, e.g.

```
int first = 0;
int last = -1;

if (condition1) {
    first = 1;
    last = 10;
} else if (condition2) {
    first = 3;
    last  = 7;
}

for ( int i = first; i <= last; i++ )
    execute set A
```

Note that initializing `last` to be less than `first` prevents the body of the loop from running if neither condition is met.

---

**The answer to Version 2 of the question:**

Here's the code from the question. I've made some changes for clarity, and to make the question more concrete.

```
if (cond1)
    for (initA;condA;updateA)
        execute SetX
else if (cond2)
    for (initB;condB;updateB)
        execute SetX
```

Here's the refactored code

```
int is1 = cond1;
int is2 = is1 ? 0 : cond2;

if (is1)
    initA;
if (is2)
    initB;

while ( (is1 && condA) || (is2 && condB) )
{
    execute SetX
    if ( is1 )
        updateA;
    if ( is2 )
        updateB;
}
```

Comment: The pseudo code snippet for the second version is the exact representation of my problem. The re-factored code is one way using which I wont have to execute/copy the statements of set X at two places. However, any further suggestions are open.

Answer (score 1):

A function, maybe?

```
void func_A() {
    printf("Here0\n");
    printf("Here1\n");
}

...

if(a < b) {
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        func_A()
    }
}
else if(a == b) {
    for(i = 3; i <= 7; i++) {
        func_A()
    }
}
```

Or if you want to only make one call/block:

```
if(a < b) {
    min = 1; max = 10;
}
else if(a == b) {
    min = 3; max = 7;
}
for(i = 3; i <= 7; i++) {
    printf("Here0\n");
    printf("Here1\n");
}
```

Comment: The set is another representation of function. I'll have to create multiple functions for this which I want to avoid.

Comment: @rango: Why? If you want something specific, I'll need a hard example. This fits your question as far as I can see.

Comment: I've update the question now. If you still need any further example let me know!!

Comment: @rango: Well, it still seems to fit.. I'd recommend adding examples of actual C statements and what you've already tried; that would give people here an idea of why your solution was giving you problems.